# Launching failed because directory '/remote_debugger' in the container is empty. .Net 8

Tags: c#, docker, docker-compose, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-8

Launching failed because directory '/remote_debugger' in the container is empty. This might be caused by Shared Drives credentials used by Docker Desktop being out of date. Try resetting the credentials in the Shared Drives page of the Docker Desktop Settings and then restart Docker.
[Launching failed because directory '/remote_debugger' in the container is empty. This might be caused by Shared Drives credentials used by Docker Desktop being out of date. Try resetting the credentials in the Shared Drives page of the Docker Desktop Settings and then restart Docker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9bSX.png)

My Docker File :

```
#See https://aka.ms/customizecontainer to learn how to customize your debug container and how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
USER app
WORKDIR /app


FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Debug 
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Samurai V2 .Net 8/SamuraiV2.Net 8.csproj", "Samurai V2 .Net 8/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./Samurai V2 .Net 8/./SamuraiV2.Net 8.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Samurai V2 .Net 8"
RUN dotnet build "./SamuraiV2.Net 8.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build


ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:8080;http://+:8081
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 8081

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Debug
RUN dotnet publish "./SamuraiV2.Net 8.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "SamuraiV2.Net 8.dll"]
```

MY DockercomposeFile

```
version: '3.4'

networks:
   Samurai:
    driver: bridge

services:
  DockerSqlServer:
    container_name: DockerSqlServer
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
    ports:
      - "8002:1433"
    environment:
     - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
     - SA_PASSWORD=Password123
    networks:
      - Samurai
  samuraiv2.net8:
    container_name: SamuraiAPP
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}samuraiv2net8
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Samurai V2 .Net 8/Dockerfile
    ports:
        - "8081:80"
    depends_on:
    - DockerSqlServer
    environment:
     - DB_HOST=DockerSqlServer
     - DB_NAME=BoookManagement
     - DB_SA_PASSWORD=Password123
    networks:
      - Samurai
```